# Sample Spring RestTemplate implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, github, resttemplate

I want to push some archived files into GITHub from my local spring application.

```
repos/{:user}/{:repo}/git/refs/heads/{:branchname}

{
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("XXXXXX", 8080));
    requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    String url = new String("https://api.github.com/repos/XXX/MyApplication/git/refs/heads/XXX");
    Map<String, String> req = new HashMap<String,String>();
    req.put("sha", "9a7fd370e28ea7a4bc8242e7f234s5ed07042cb88");
    String jsonObject = JSONParser.quote(payload);
    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers1);
   restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,httpEntity,Object.class);
}

Error: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
```

Using the below POST API, I get '404 not found error'.

```
Method : POST
URL : https://api.github.com/repos/{:user}/{:repo}/git/refs/heads/{:branchname}
{
  "sha": "{:new-commit-sha}"
}
```

Can you any one provide sample Spring RestTemplate implementation for above api?

Answer (score 1):

i found issue in above scenario. for this above POST client userId and password in Headers and it is wrong.

we need to provide userId and Password in BasicAutherizationInceptors class like below.

```
resttemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAutherizationInterceptor(userId,Pwd));
```